# Customization of Notes and Attachment

Tags: visualforce

I have requirement like i want to customize notes and Attachment related list, so  Can we Customize Notes and Attachment Related List?

Comment: You can always build your own Visualforce page and use it on layouts. I don't think there are other solutions

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to customize the related list. There's tons of ideas you can vote on. I suggest you vote for future enhancements. In the meantime, you could consider creating a Visualforce page to show those notes. See this list of ideas you can vote on.

- [Customize Notes and Attachments](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ajV3AAI)
- [Ability to Customize 'Notes and Attachments' Related List](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l9kkAAA)
- [Leads Tab Notes Section: Customize with Additional Field](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bZbJAAU)
- [Customized Security Settings for Notes/Attachments](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrJeAAK)
- [Add custom fields to notes object](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqjSAAS)
- [Make Notes & Attachments Related List Customizable](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007N6wAAE)
- [Customize Standard Related Lists Fully](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqxOAAS)

Answer (score 2):

Notes & Attachments comes as is.  There is no ability to customise it.

Perhaps describe the problem you're trying to solve and maybe someone might have some ideas about it.

Comment: I want to show Note body in my related List