# Add custom field to attachment related list

Tags: visualforce, attachment, related-list

I need to add a custom field to attachment related list, so that while uploading documents user can specify business type of document. I found it is not possible to customize standard attachment related list. Is there no option other than using visualforce ? How can i use visualforce to reuse existing columns available in attachments related list ?

Comment: Name and Description are fields which you can utilize. Else are system populated.

Comment: Have a look here, similar: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89901/customization-of-notes-and-attachment .  I would recommend looking at creating your own Visualforce page (I've hardcoded a description via Visualforce but it ultimately depends on your use cases (do you need to report on this field?)) and maybe voting on the idea:  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ajV3AAI.  Ultimately it isn't possible to add a custom field to the Notes/Attachment related list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am planning to use this approach :
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2014/05/30/how-to-customize-salesforce-attachments/